# Projection matrix of projection into the complement.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

**Background**:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$, and let $V=V_1⨁V_2$ be a direct sum of two subspaces. $∀{\bf v}∈V,{\bf v}={\bf v}_1+{\bf v}_2$ for some ${\bf v}_1∈V_1,{\bf v}_2∈V_2$, and we say ${\bf v} _1$ is a projection of ${\bf v}$ into subspace $V_1$, denoted by ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}}:V \to V$ (we still let the codomain of be $V$ rather than $V_1$ for mathematical convenience). Projection is a linear map, and the matrix representing it is called the projection matrix.
>
> We can show the projection matrix of ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}$ is idempotent. For any ${\bf v}_1∈V_1$, we have its direct decomposition ${\bf v}_1={\bf v}_1+{\bf 0}$, then
>
> ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{{\mathbf{v}}_1} = {{\mathbf{v}}_1} \Rightarrow {\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}\left( {{\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}}} \right) = {\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}},\forall {\mathbf{v}} \in V$
>
> Let $\bf V$ be a basis of $V$, and let $\bf A$ be the matrix of ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}$, then
>
> ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}} = {\mathbf{VA}}\left[ {\mathbf{v}} \right] \Rightarrow \left[ {{\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}}} \right] = {\mathbf{A}}\left[ {\mathbf{v}} \right] \Rightarrow {\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}\left( {{\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}}} \right) = {\mathbf{VA}}\left[ {{\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}}} \right] = {\mathbf{V}}{{\mathbf{A}}^2}\left[ {\mathbf{v}} \right]$
>
> where $[{\bf v}]$ denotes the coordinate of $\bf v$ with respect to basis $\bf V$. And then
>
> ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}\left( {{\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}}} \right) = {\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{\mathbf{v}} \Rightarrow {\mathbf{V}}{{\mathbf{A}}^2}\left[ {\mathbf{v}} \right] = {\mathbf{VA}}\left[ {\mathbf{v}} \right] \Rightarrow {{\mathbf{A}}^2}\left[ {\mathbf{v}} \right] = {\mathbf{A}}\left[ {\mathbf{v}} \right]$
>
> Since $[{\bf v}]$ is arbitrary coordinate in $F^n$, thus ${\bf A}^2={\bf A}$. Thus, the projection matrix is idempotent.

**Problem**:

Now the problem is to show ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_2}}}$ can be represented by ${\mathbf{I}} - {\mathbf{A}}$. Let $\bf B$ denote the matrix of ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_2}}}$, I can show

> ${\mathbf{AB}} = {\mathbf{BA}} = {\mathbf{O}}$

For example,

> ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}{{\mathbf{v}}_2} = {\bf 0},\forall {{\mathbf{v}}_2} \in {V_2} \Rightarrow {\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}\left( {{\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_2}}}{\mathbf{v}}} \right) = {\bf 0} \Rightarrow {\mathbf{AB}}\left[ {\mathbf{v}} \right] = 0,\forall \left[ {\mathbf{v}} \right] \in {F^n} \Rightarrow {\mathbf{AB}} = {\mathbf{O}}$

Plus the idempotence,

> ${{\mathbf{B}}^{\mathbf{2}}} = {\mathbf{B}},{{\mathbf{A}}^2} = {\mathbf{A}}$

However, I still don't see why ${\mathbf{B}} = {\mathbf{I}} - {\mathbf{A}}$. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_2}}}({\mathbf{v}}) = {\mathbf{v}} - {\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}({\mathbf{v}})$ for any ${\bf v}\in V$, that is, ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_2}}}$ is the sum of two linear maps: the identity map and $ - {\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_{{V_1}}}$, which are represented by $\bf I$ and $-{\bf A}$ resepectively, thus its matrix is ${\mathbf{I}} - {\mathbf{A}}$.